# Change state mode between components

Tags: reactjs

I have the following 3 components: SectionBox(the parent), SectionData and Section (the children). With the following code I try to share data between these three components, such that when I click the button in the Section component, I can see the change in SectionData component.
I tried to do so with some examples that I saw here, by playing with the 'state' object and pass a function as a parameter, but it's not working.
Here's my code:

*

```
import React from 'react';
import Section from './Section';
import SectionData from './SectionData';

export default class SectionBox extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
          dataToShow: "A"
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-md-2">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Section onUpdate={this.changeDataToShowState.bind(this)} title="A"/>
                    <Section onUpdate={this.changeDataToShowState.bind(this)} title="B"/>
                    <Section onUpdate={this.changeDataToShowState.bind(this)} title="C"/>
                </div>
                <SectionData data = {this.state.dataToShow}/>
            </div>

    changeDataToShowState (val) {
        this.setState({dataToShow: val});
    }
}
```

**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Section extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="float-box">
                    <button onclick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.title}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }

    handleClick() {
        var stateMode = this.props.title;
        this.props.onUpdate(stateMode);
    }
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react';

export default class SectionData extends React.Component {

    render() {
        var result;

        if (this.props.data === "A") {
            result = "A";
        } else {
            result = "B or C";
        }

        return (
             <div className="col-md-10">
                 <div className="float-box-content">
                     <div>{result}</div>
                 </div>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a typo, it's not "onclick", it's "onClick".

```
 <button onclick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.title}</button>
```

should be

```
 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.title}</button>
```